# Clustering the UCI adult data set

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to perform k-means cluster analysis on the UCI adult data set.

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1).astype(int))
y = np.array(df['class'])

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
y_km=km.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[y_km==0,0], X[y_km==0,1], s=50, c='lightgreen',  marker='s', label='cluster 1')

plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:,0], km.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=250, marker='*', c='red', label='centroids')
```

graph: [image: graph]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've spent a long time on this. Any help would be appreciated.

dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult

I have to use k-means as this is coursework.

MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

features=["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education-num", "marital-status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", "capital-gain","capital-loss", "hours-per-week", "native-country", "class"]
df = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/data-adult/adult.data", names=features)
df['class'] = df["class"].apply(lambda x:0 if x==' <=50K' else 1)

labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(df['sex'])
df['sex'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['sex'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['occupation'])
df['occupation'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['occupation'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['workclass'])
df['workclass'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['workclass'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['education'])
df['education'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['education'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['marital-status'])
df['marital-status'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['marital-status'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['relationship'])
df['relationship'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['relationship'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['race'])
df['race'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['race'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['native-country'])
df['native-country'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['native-country'])

X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1).astype(int))
y = np.array(df['class'])

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
y_km=km.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(X[y_km==0,0], X[y_km==0,1], s=50, c='lightgreen',  label='cluster 1')

plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:,0], km.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=250, marker='*', c='red', label='centroids')
```

Comment: K means is the wrong algorithm for data with this shape. Try [dbscan](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.dbscan.html) instead

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I would like to generate a graph showing 2 k-means clusters based on 'class' in the database.
At the moment the graph comes out with lines, I don't understand why

Comment: well your `marker` parameter is a square - `s`. remove that and these will be dots. They are lines just because the squares are overlapping.

Comment: I have done this, the graph looks better but that data is still placed in multiple straight lines as shown when it should be in clusters.
I think this is due to either how I have prepared the data or how I have plotted it.

Comment: Are you sure that you referenced the correct dataset? The `adult` dataset doesn't seem to have a class feature... Or is `class` == `workclass`?

Comment: I see now, it isn't mentioned on the website for some reason, it is definitely a column in my dataset as I have generated previous graphs on the data

Comment: And can you provide an MCVE so that we can quickly replicate your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: From the looks of it I guess the feature values of column 1 (whats on the Y-axis) are integer based. That is what creating the 'straight' lines in the graph.

Comment: Probably helpful in this context: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

features=["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education-num", "marital-status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", "capital-gain","capital-loss", "hours-per-week", "native-country", "class"]
df = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/data-adult/adult.data", names=features)
df['class'] = df["class"].apply(lambda x:0 if x==' <=50K' else 1)

labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(df['sex'])
df['sex'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['sex'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['occupation'])
df['occupation'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['occupation'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['workclass'])
df['workclass'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['workclass'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['education'])
df['education'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['education'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['marital-status'])
df['marital-status'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['marital-status'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['relationship'])
df['relationship'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['relationship'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['race'])
df['race'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['race'])
labelEncoder.fit(df['native-country'])
df['native-country'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['native-country'])

X = np.array(df.drop(['class'], 1).astype(int))
y = np.array(df['class'])

#Apply normalization to your feature vectors

# fit scaler on training data
norm = MinMaxScaler().fit(X)

# transform training data
X_norm = norm.transform(X)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X_norm)

#This will generate number of predicted labels for each class
kmeans_labels = kmeans.labels_
unique_labels, unique_counts = np.unique(kmeans_labels, return_counts=True)
dict(zip(unique_labels, unique_counts))

#accuracy measure of your model can be done by
accuracy = accuracy_score(y, kmeans_labels)
print("k means prediction accuracy:", accuracy)
```